# Как отфильтровать вложенный массив с объектами с вложенным массивом

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, фильтрация

Всем привет, уже 2 дня мучаюсь с фильтрацией.

Структура которую я хочу отфильтровать:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    attributes: [
      { name: "hello", value: "World" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "student" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    attributes: [
      { name: "baz", value: "bar" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "student" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    attributes: [
      { name: "foo", value: "bar" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "schoolboy" }
    ]
  }
];
```

На вход получаю такие данные:

```
{
  filterValue: "student",
  filterField: "Vanya"
}
```

На выходе я хочу получить массив объектов в которых attrbiutes поле соответствуют заданному фильтру.

Вот так:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    attributes: [
      { name: "hello", value: "World" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "student" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    attributes: [
      { name: "baz", value: "bar" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "student" }
    ]
  },
]
```

**Буду максимально признателен любому ответу, или хотябы подсказке куда копать!**

Comment: так и в чем загвоздка? 2 дня вы мучились, код то есть в итоге какой-то? `data.filter( v => ...)` может пытались использовтаь, сделать там внутри что-то с `v.attributes` ?

Comment: такой вопрос почему вы закрываете скобки после объекта attributes если они нигде не открываются или тут не полный код?

Comment: @teran, если вам нужны мои попытки, и вы посмотря на них, готовы помочь, я могу их вам предоставить в чате

Comment: @user469485 правила сообщества требуют к учебным задачам прикладывать решения, в противном случае такие вопросы закрываются обычно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно решить вот так.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    attributes: [
      { name: "hello", value: "World" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "student" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    attributes: [
      { name: "baz", value: "bar" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "student" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    attributes: [
      { name: "foo", value: "bar" },
      { name: "Vanya", value: "schoolboy" }
    ]
  }
];

const filter = {
  filterValue: "student",
  filterField: "Vanya"
}

const filterdData = data.filter((item) => {
    if(item.attributes.length) {
        for (var prop in item.attributes) {
          if(item.attributes[prop]['name'] === filter.filterField && item.attributes[prop]['value'] === filter.filterValue) {
              return true
          }
        }
    }
    return false
})

console.log(filterdData)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: `data,filter(d => d.attributes.some(a => a.name == "X" && a.value == "Y"))`